# Misunderstanding Cayley's Theorem…?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Cayley Theorem states that *any* group is isomorphic to some group of permutation.

Now groups of permutations is finite right? So doesn't imply that the group $G$ that isomorphic to $S_G$ must also be countable?

I am pretty new to group theory so this may seem like an absurd question

Comment: No, a group of permutations need not be finite (or countable).

Comment: A permutation on $G$ is just a bijective function from $G\to G$. So if $G$ is not finite by swapping 2 Elements we will have infinite many bijections

Comment: Unfortunately Wikipedia is confusing on this point: its statement of Cayley's theorem is "every group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric group acting on $G$", but when you follow the link for "symmetric group", the article only talks about _finite_ groups. Maybe that led the OP astray.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#Definition_and_first_properties

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh, I am still confused. Because $|S_n| = n!$ which is finite for any $n$. So I don't see how that can be uncountable.

Comment: You also want to throw a "subgroup of" in there somewhere.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: my mistake. Anyway, my point is that the opening sentence only talks about finite symmetric groups, which might already confuse some readers. (Although really one would have to be very sleep- or caffeine-deprived (as I evidently am this morning) not to see the mentions of infinite symmetric groups.)

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Actually, introductions of articles are often misleading on Wikipedia, and you have to dig deeper into the article to find what you are looking for. As somebody once pointed me to, one should never use Wikipedia as a dictionary. ;-)

Comment: @sidht: But not every group of permutations is of the form $S_n$. The answer below gives a good example of this.

Comment: I will take a second look later at the Wikipedia article on symmetric groups, and see whether one can eliminate the ambiguity without making the article top-heavy. Another possibility (perhaps simpler) is to edit the article on Cayley's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

No. For example, the group of permutations of the natural numbers $S_{\mathbb{N}}$ is clearly infinite (for example, $(1, n)$ is an element for every number $n$, and as there are infinitely many numbers $n$...). Less clear is that it is, in fact, uncountably infinite. This is because you can embed $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ into $S_{\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}}\cong S_{\mathbb{N}}$ via the following map (note that I am assuming that $0$ is not a natural number, which is a [valid convention](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNumber.html)).
$$
\{s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n, \ldots\}\mapsto
\begin{cases}
(s_1s_2\cdots s_n\cdots) &\mbox{ if } n>1\\
(s_1, 0) &\mbox{ if } n=1
\end{cases}
$$

**Exercise:** Prove that every countable group embeds into $S_{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: Shouldn't you get something like $|\mathcal{P}(G)|=|2^G|=2^{|G|} \leq |S_G|$ very easy ?

Comment: I mean at least for $|G|\geq 4$

Comment: @Dominic It is not *immediately* obvious (at least to me) that $|\mathcal{P}(G)|\leq |S_G|$. So, I figured this counts as "less clear" (especially as the "less than" is comparing it to the fact that $S_{\mathbb{N}}$ is infinite!).

Comment: @user1729, so answering your example. Then for each $n$, label it with the natural numbers, making it countable?

Comment: @sidht because the numbers of Elements in $A^B$ is $|A|^{|B|}$, in the finite case this is quite immediate because you may chose $|A|$ between $|B|$ Elements

Comment: @sidht The fact that $|\mathcal{P}(S)|>|S|$ is well-known, and usually introduced in a first or second course on general pure maths.

Comment: (@sidht Also, I don't understand your first comment. Which example? Do you mean the exercise, or the bit with the map?)

Comment: @sidht No, $2^A$, for a set $A$, is the set of applications from $A$ to $\{1,2\}$, or equivalently $\mathcal{P}(A)$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, oh shoot you are right. I forgot this was one of those crazy notations.

Comment: @user1729, "for example, (1,n) is an element for every number n, and as there are infinitely many numbers n…)" was what my first comment refers to.

Comment: @sidht Not as crazy as you may think, since for $a^b$ and integer $a,b$, you get the cardinal of $A^B$ where $\mathrm{Card} A=a$ and $\mathrm{Card} B=b$. This notation, of polish origin (I first read it in Kuratowski's textbook on topology) is much more understandable than $\mathcal{P}(A)$, $\mathfrak{B}(A)$, or any odd letter.

Comment: @user1729 your mapping is not injective as all singletones are mapped on the identity if i am not wrong

Comment: @user1729 still not injective as the image of $\{0,1\}$ is the same as the image of $\{0\}$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Fixed. I cheated.

Comment: @user1729, when you write say $(s_1, s_2) \to (s_1,s_2)$, what are these $s_is$? Are they numbers?